# How to access required element of HTML in shiny

Tags: html, r, validation, shiny, user-input

I am working on form where i am taking inputs from users and all fields are mandatory and have validations like valid emailid, only 6 digit pincode.I have created a form on HTML and all validations are working fine on HTML by using "required" element of HTML which makes input type mandatory also input type email of HTML put all the validations required for an emailid.

But i want to achieve same thing in shiny internal UI form i tried a lot by accessing html tags inside shiny but everytime i am getting error for required element that i placed inside input tag of shiny.

Below attached image is from HTML form that i created using raw HTML but i want to achieve same thing in my shiny internal form.
[image]

Code for the above image:

```
<input type="email" name="emailid" value="" placeholder="Enter valid email id" required>
```

Can anyone help me how to achieve the same.Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this would be in two parts.  First, I'd put an observer on `input$emailid` to check that the user has entered a valid email address.  If they haven't I'd then use the `shinyFeedback` package to display a pop-up prompting the user to put things right.  You could also use `shinyFeedback` to display the prompt you show in your screen grab when the input is empty, but my own personal opinion is that that would be overkill.

Something like:

```
library(shinyFeedback)
observeEvent(input$emailid, {
    feedbackDanger(
      "emailid", 
      !isValidEmailAddress(input$emailid), 
      "Please enter a valid email address"
    )
})
```

To get `shinyFeedback` to work you need to add `useShinyFeedback()` at the start of your ui page.  Furter details [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyFeedback/vignettes/shinyFeedback-intro.html).  Note that `isValidEmailAddress()` is a function you'll need to write yourself.